# Intent is producing null object reference when moving from splash activity to main Activity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

Every Thing was working fine before, and now when i run my app it starts producing this error and my app is keep crashing.

This error is keep coming

android.content.Intent android.content.Intent.putExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Here is my Splash Activity Code.

Oncreate Method code is below

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SplashActivity.this);

        fragmentKey=0;
        intiViews();

        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {

            redirectingIntent.putExtra("fragmentKey", fragmentKey);
            startActivity(redirectingIntent);
            finish();

        }, 3000);
```

InitViews Method code is given below

```
    private void intiViews() {
        userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Common.USER_REF);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //Check User if it exist
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            CheckUserFromFirebase(user);
        } else {
            redirectingIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            fragmentKey = 0;
        }

    }

    private void CheckUserFromFirebase(final FirebaseUser user) {
        userRef.child(user.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

                    UserModel userModel = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserModel.class);
                    updateUser(userModel);
                    redirectingIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    fragmentKey = 0;
                } else {
                    RegisterUser();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(SplashActivity.this, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here i am updating my user with the user model that is uploaded to the firebase

```
    private void updateUser(UserModel model) {
        Common.CurrentUser = model;
        Common.CurrentUser.setUid(user.getUid());
    }
```

if there is no registered user of given uid,then intent will go to register activity

```
    private void RegisterUser() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Data found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        redirectingIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
        fragmentKey = 1;
    }

}
```

Comment: i have  applied invalidate catches and restart but still no result.

Comment: `redirectingIntent` is not getting initialised. Check your conditions and make sure `redirectingIntent` is initialised before the handler gets executed.

Comment: Thanks for help, error is removed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//update by this

 new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {
        if(redirectingIntent != null && fragmentKey != null)    
        {
            redirectingIntent.putExtra("fragmentKey", fragmentKey);
            startActivity(redirectingIntent);
            finish();
        }

    }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would avoid the delayed Handler as it's prone to errors; more exactly this code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(() -> {

        redirectingIntent.putExtra("fragmentKey", fragmentKey);
        startActivity(redirectingIntent);
        finish();

}, 3000);
```

I would make another method that takes care of redirecting and call it whenever I need

```
private void redirectToNextActivity(fragmentKey: Integer) {
    if (redirectingIntent != null ) {
        redirectingIntent.putExtra("fragmentKey", fragmentKey);
        startActivity(redirectingIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using delayed Handler() just because of splash screen.